# HEC RAS and storm sewer

Tags: civil-engineering, hydrology

It is required to simulate the surface runoff in the city on the basis of the DEM and see how well the storm drains are coping. But I do not know how to make a water intake not from the edge of the calculated geometry limited by the volume that the grid can take in (there is data on how much water each grid can take in.) How can this be done?